# Angular prevent application render on existing HTML

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, prerender

Currently, I have an Angular application hosted on .NET Core web server. The application is for public users so we want to increase the First Contentful Paint (FCP). We don't use Angular Universal but created a similar solution.

We use a separate service with PuppeteerSharp to navigate to Angular routes, render the page and then save all the output HTML into cache. The Angular pages are rendered perfectly. When users navigate to the page, we return cached HTML immediately.

However Angular script then will run, then we have this situation:

User sees the rendered page quickly -> (Angular script loaded) -> Page goes blank -> Keep blank for a while -> Angular script executed and data is loaded -> Users now can interact.

So I want to ask how to prevent Angular from being loaded again? We want the solution exactly like Universal Pre-render or Server-render?

The best solution we have now is :

- We use the hosting .NET Core to remove main.....js script of Angular from cached HTML
- Only we add the script after users have interact with the page

This way will raise the FCP and increase Lighthouse Performance point, but really it's not what we're looking for?

Comment: before the angular 16 there was no possibility to hydrate the application without destruction. I believe you have to upgrade to A16 at least and dive deeper into how to make it work with your solution. If you were using standard angular universal solution - you could just add `provideClientHydration()` to root providers and that is it